# How to replace or update node text in XML file?

Tags: c#, xml

Below is my XML data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<students>
<student>
<name>James</name>
<age>34</age>
</student>
<student>
<name>Shawn</name>
<age>30</age>
</student>
<student>
<name>Scott</name>
<age>35</age>
</student>
</students>
```

**below is my c# code**

```
XmlDocument myxml = new XmlDocument();
string path;
private void update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
//to fetch aplication path 
        path =System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
        myxml.Load(@"" + path + "/samplexml.xml");

//here i need to write a code 
// when i click update button i will pass new name(through textbox) to the existing node in XML file, example there is a node name called Shawn but i want to change  Shawn.k when i click update button this is the requirement 


    }
```

Please help me out if know the solution for this.

Comment: Do you have to use `XmlDocument`? Life is generally a lot simpler with `XDocument`, i.e. LINQ to XML. Next, have you got *anywhere* with your requirement at the moment? What have you tried so far? What happened?

Comment: So how would you know which Item you have to change in Xml. Do you have separate TextBoxes for changing each element?

Comment: ya thanks for your great reply Jon Skeet and Alex Jolig

Comment: My requirement is like i want to create a xml nodes from c# and save thous in to samplexml.xml file and i need to navigate records by using next and previous buttons , i done both task saving nodes in to xml file and navigating records but now i have a requirement like  i need to update

Comment: @ Alex Jolig,  ya i created separate textbox or else i will replace the text in same textbox itself when i click update button i will pass textbox name